# IndexError: list index out of range - while calling function in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

when i try to run below function from pyspark and getting index out of range error

```
key = Issue_type=["35 USC 101","35 USC § 101","35 U.S.C. 101","35 U.S.C. § 101","§ 101","35 USC 102","35 USC §102","35 U.S.C. 102","35 U.S.C. § 102","§ 102","35 USC 103","35 USC § 103","35 U.S.C. 103","35 U.S.C. § 103","§ 103","35 USC 112","35 USC § 112","35 U.S.C. 112","35 U.S.C. § 112","§ 112"]
string ="asdgas35 USC 102dl;la35 USC § 112sga35 U.S.C. § 103s;lkg           sa35 USC 101dsgslasdfhgafds;m;ldsl35 U.S.C. 101dsa   glk35 U.S.C. § 102dsaoi35 U.S.C. § 112eqw"


def find_all_words1(words, sentence):

    #all_words = re.findall(r'\w+', sentence)
    all_words=sentence
    words_found = []
    codelist = ('35 USC 122','35 USC 134','35 USC 161','35 USC 251','35 USC 257','35 USC 311','35 USC 312','35 USC 314','35 USC 315','35 USC 317','35 USC 318','35 USC 321','35 USC 324','35 USC 325','35 USC 328','37 USC 1.131','Bd. R. 121','Bd. R. 127','PER CURIAM','37 CFR 41.50','37 CFR 41.77','37 CFR 41.79','37 CFR 41.125','37 CFR 41.127','37 CFR 42.5','37 CFR 42.71','37 CFR 42.72','37 CFR 42.73','37 CFR 42.74','37 CFR 42.100','37 CFR 42.101','37 CFR 42.102','37 CFR 42.103','37 CFR 42.104','37 CFR 42.105','37 CFR 42.106','37 CFR 42.107','37 CFR 42.108','37 CFR 42.109','37 CFR 42.110','37 CFR 42.111','37 CFR 42.112','37 CFR 42.113','37 CFR 42.114','37 CFR 42.115','37 CFR 42.116','37 CFR 42.117','37 CFR 42.118','37 CFR 42.119','37 CFR 42.120','37 CFR 42.121','37 CFR 42.122','37 CFR 42.123','37 CFR 42.200','37 CFR 42.201','37 CFR 42.202','37 CFR 42.203','37 CFR 42.204','37 CFR 42.205','37 CFR 42.206','37 CFR 42.207','37 CFR 42.208','37 CFR 42.209','37 CFR 42.210','37 CFR 42.211','37 CFR 42.212','37 CFR 42.213','37 CFR 42.214','37 CFR 42.215','37 CFR 42.216','37 CFR 42.217','37 CFR 42.218','37 CFR 42.219','37 CFR 42.220','37 CFR 42.221','37 CFR 42.222','37 CFR 42.223','37 CFR 42.224','37 CFR 42.300','37 CFR 42.301','37 CFR 42.302','37 CFR 42.303','37 CFR 42.304','37 CFR 42.400','37 CFR 42.401','37 CFR 42.402','37 CFR 42.403','37 CFR 42.404','37 CFR 42.405','37 CFR 42.406','37 CFR 42.407','37 CFR 42.408','37 CFR 42.409','37 CFR 42.410','37 CFR 42.411','37 CFR 42.412')
    for word in words:
        if word in all_words:
            for i in range (0,len(codelist)-1):
                print(codelist[i])
                code = codelist[i].split(' ')[2]
                print(code)
                ind = len(code)
                if word[-int(ind):] == str(code):
                    words_found.append(codelist[i])
    return set(words_found)
c=find_all_words1(key,string)
print(c)
```

Hi Guys,
please help me how to fix index out of range 
Thanks in advance
Raj

Comment: Please, post always full traceback you get, it contains valuable information, don't give just the last line

Comment: i am getting error just index out of range only nothing any other than... thing is i have to match the value from list and assign the default value from codelist

Comment: No, you are getting something like Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xxx\example.py", line 21, in <module>
    c=find_all_words1(key,string)
  File "C:\xxx\example.py", line 15, in find_all_words1
    code = codelist[i].split(' ')[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-76-c34c61da4d94>", line 17, in find_all_words1
    code = codelist[i].split(' ')[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxxx", line 21, in <module>
    c=find_all_words1(key,string)
  File "xxxxx", line 15, in find_all_words1
    code = codelist[i].split(' ')[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

In `codelist` you have element `'PER CURIAM'`. When you split it at `' '` you get two-elemnt tuple, i.e. there is no element with index 2 and you get  `IndexError` on this line `codelist[i].split(' ')[2]` - that is why I asked for full traceback.

Comment: Thanks Buran for quick response and i will take that element and  put separately